# i can't limit a javascript animation in time

Tags: javascript

I have to code an animation for an array. Every box, one by one, will take a white color for 3000 ms. But it's not working. Can you help me?

```
function searchNumber(){
    var taille;
    for(var i=0; i<taille; i++) {
        tabRect[i].hide("5000");
        tabRect[i].show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe in words what you want the animation sequence to be.  It is not entirely clear from your current question.  Also, since `taille` is not defined, it will not work in your `for` loop.  And, please show what `tabRect` is.

Comment: Thank you for your ansewer! The animation should show that all the values in the array will be treated one by one (we are searching for the max for a selection sort) . **taille** is the size of the array . **tabRect** is a set of an element "forme" defined  like this : `
               ` forme= paper.rect(400, this.y, 50,50).attr({fill:color}).animate(animIntroCase(this.x));`
 I'm sorry if it's not clear . Please tell me if i should put all the code . Thank you again.

Comment: The  way this site works is that you should use the "edit" link and add the additional description to your question directly.  People should not have to read comments to understand your question.  You question should be entirely clear by itself.  The reason you are getting downvotes on your question is that it is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with **CSS3**, is not necessary **javascript** for that:

https://jsfiddle.net/rzcdqh8k/

```
.animation {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red; //original color
    -webkit-animation-name: example;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;} //original color
    to {background-color: white;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;} //original color
    to {background-color: white;}
}
```